# Wordpress with WooCommerce add_actions not working

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a function (hook) after payment is completed in Wordpress where i use the plugin woocomerce.

The [documentation](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/extending/hooks/) for woocommere says that there is an action called "woocommerce_payment_complete" and a filter called "woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status"

Nothing is happend, when i try to use them

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'do_something_foo');

function do_something_foo() {
    wp_die("foo!");

}
```

Why doesn't it work ?

Thanks !

Comment: have you found solution for this thing? Im struggling with the very same issue.

Comment: Have you tried putting the add_action statement below the function? (Not sure if that will help, but that's how it seems to be done in every wordpress source file I've looked in)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience around woocommerce I've always had much more success hooking the order status action, perhaps this is a viable alternative for your solution?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'do_something_foo' );

   function do_something_foo() {
   wp_die("foo!");

}
```